# How to delete tableviewcell automatically

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an array like [1...100], and I display it in a UITableView. When I add a cell to that tableview, I want the cell before it to be deleted automatically. Is this possible? I tried many solutions, and I know how to delete a cell by using the commit editing style method, but the the cell needs be deleted automatically, not with user input.

Comment: If you want to add and delete two contiguous cells at the same time why don't you just **update** the cell?

Comment: Is there any reference how to update cell

Comment: You are supposed to have a data source array. Instead of appending a new item update the properties of the previous item with the new data and reload the tableview.

Comment: How to update the cell

Comment: Don't update the cell (the view) directly, update the data source (the model) and reload the table view, that updates the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change your model and then reload the table. Let's say, as per your example, that your table contains rows with 1 to 100 in them. Your model would look like this:

```
var model = [1..<100]
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you would set the text of every cell to an item in the array. Therefore, if you update the model and reload the table view, that will "automatically" delete cells. Your adding function, which deletes the last cell before adding a new one, might look like this:

```
func addItem(n: Int) {
    model.removeLast()
    model.append(n)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This allows you to manipulate the model however you want, and then update your table without having to worry about working with removing and updating cells.

Comment: Suppose if  want to add 55 . In between 1 to 100 the 55 will it be deleted